# How to support auto resizing UITableViewCell with a UILabel in it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to figure out how get the correct height for my tableview cell that contains a uitextview so that all the content in the uitextview will be display. The textview is not editable and not scrollable, which means that the string for the uitextview is known. I tried simply returning the height of the tableview cell that is in the storyboard in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but that cuts off the content if it is too large. I also tried calculating the height for the textView in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but it throws an error at runtime:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let cellInfo = UserCellsArray[indexPath.section]
        switch cellInfo {
        case .userInfo: return 104
        case .ubio:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellInfo.description, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableViewCell //error
            let oldHeight = cell.userBio.frame.size.height
            cell.userBio.text = self.bio
            var bodyframe = cell.userBio.frame
            bodyframe.size = cell.userBio.contentSize
            let newHeight = cell.userBio.contentSize.height
            return tableView.rowHeight - oldHeight + newHeight
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any specific reasons why you are using TextView instead of UILabel?

Comment: @Shripada Not really other than I wasn't sure how to format it with auto layout within the tableviewcell considering a fair amount of text would be added to the label. I can easily switch to a label if it makes the problem easier.

Comment: yes you can have a resizable UILabel, using constraints and few settings for UITableView, I will try to post an answer in a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Need to use auto layout in your cell and set up appropriate constraints for UILabel. Since we want to resize the UILabel to fit the text set to it, we will set the number of lines value to 0. And then set the leading, trailing, bottom and top constraints to the UILabel. Please see screenshots here:

   [image: Lines as 0]
   [image]
2. In your Table View controller > viewDidLoad call these two lines:

   ```
     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0  //Give an approximation here
     tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```

   and also implement delegate method:

   ```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }
   ```