# How to Achieve Self-Resizing Height for UITableViewCell and a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uistackview

I have a UITableViewCell, with a UIView bottom container since I'm new around here I'll leave this link so you can get the idea:

[Basic Static Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Nh0.png)

The bottom container does also use a Stack View at its right side to hold those "Options" as shown in the Image, I need to make the cell all dynamic since sometimes I can have 2 options, to 15 options and well it wouldn't look good setting it up with 15 options and only show 2 options, I'm having quite a rough time trying to think how to achieve this behavior here's another image to clarify what I'm trying to do:

[Behavior Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuavN.png)

I'm just looking for tips/recommendations on how would I achieve this behavior any source of info, anything, and thanks so much in advance and if I wasn't clear enough please let me know I tried my best with the images trying to explain what I want to do but if it wasn't enough do let me know! Couldn't find an specific answer to this kind of behavior so yeah my bad if this was already asked.

EDIT: The options within the right side of the bottom container that are inside the UIStackView are little UIViews with just a label and a button, my bad.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348555/how-to-support-auto-resizing-uitableviewcell-with-a-uilabel-in-it  This is something I wish Apple would implement into the language in an easier fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the info and your time reading the thread @Dom however I see that's for TextViews, I forgot to mention what's actually inside the stack view that holds the options, they are just little UIViews added with a label and a button! if there's a detail that I left out I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend came up with a nice idea, what he ended up doing was to assign different heights based on how many options we would receive so there was no need to edit the constraints in auto-layout or something like that, since the options were dynamically added to the stack view as shown in the images and the maximum of options that we would get was 15, he based different sizes such as small, medium, large, with different values depending on how many options we would get!